# Oracle SQL CLOB Compare from multiple joins

Tags: sql, database, oracle, clob

Due to a requirements change, the relationship between tables has meant I cannot use request_id as a join to compare 2 tables as the request_id's do not match. I will have to use the 2 order_no's, but these are located in different tables.

This is the query I have, and have made work using the request_id.

```
SELECT rm.order_no,
   r.request_id as INL_ID,
   rr.request_id as INLR_ID,
   r.request as INL_REQUEST,
   rr.request as INLR_REQUEST
  FROM   inl_mml_requests r
   LEFT JOIN inlr_mml_requests rr
   ON (   rr.request_id = r.request_id
      AND dbms_lob.compare(rr.request, r.request) <> 0 )
left JOIN inl_request_message rm
   ON (NVL(SUBSTR(r.request_id , 0, INSTR(r.request_id, '_')-1), r.request_id) = 
rm.request_id)
WHERE rr.request_id is not null;
```

I now need to substitute request_id as the join with order_no and compare the request that way.

Here is a table relationship graph:
[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxiCL.png)

I have tried this for far but was not successful:

```
SELECT rm.order_no as INL_ORDER_ID,
   rmr.siebel_order_no as INLR_ORDER_ID,
   r.request_id as INL_ID,
   rr.request_id as INLR_ID,
   r.request as INL_REQUEST,
   rr.request as INLR_REQUEST
   FROM   inl_mml_requests r
   INNER JOIN inl_request_message rm
  on r.request_id = rm.request_id
 INNER JOIN inlr_order_id rmr
on rm.order_no = rmr.siebel_order_no
   LEFT JOIN inlr_mml_requests rr
   ON (   rr.request_id = r.request_id
      AND dbms_lob.compare(rr.request, r.request) <> 0 )
left JOIN inl_request_message rm
   ON (NVL(SUBSTR(r.request_id , 0, INSTR(r.request_id, '_')-1), r.request_id) = 
  rm.request_id)

 WHERE rr.request_id is not null;
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the question and the title? What is your exact issue? What does "was not successful" mean? If you have any errors, then post the error message. If the output of your code is not what you expect, then post some sample data and desired output in text format

Comment: Hi there, yes the output is not what I expect. The sample output is just empty but runs successfully. It is not completing the comparison I am after.